# Parse User Input

Tags: java

I want to add a number if user enters "add 5", i want to initialize the variable if user enters "set 5". How can I do it in java?

```
  import java.io.*;
  import java.math.*;
  import java.text.*;
  import java.util.*;
  import java.util.regex.*;

   public class Solution {

    /*
 * Complete the maximumProgramValue function below.
 */
 static long maximumProgramValue(int n) {
    /*
     * Write your code here.
     */

}

private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new 
                            FileWriter(System.getenv("OUTPUT_PATH")));

    int n = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])*");

    long result = maximumProgramValue(n);

    bufferedWriter.write(String.valueOf(result));
    bufferedWriter.newLine();

    bufferedWriter.close();

    scanner.close();
   }
}
```

help me for solving it, that how can I use it to get an answer, I have been stuck here for long please help soon thanks

Comment: Perhaps explaining properly instead of copy/paste nonsense text would help.

Answer (score 0):

i didn't catch your code but here is the answer of your question

```
import java.util.*;

public class aaaaa {

private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    String n = scanner.next();
        scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])*");

       if(n.equals("add 5")){
          //add number here
       }
       else if (n.equals("set 5")){
            //set the number here
       }


} 


}
```